Getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Removing a detached instance"
I am trying to delete a old child entities, create new child entities, update grandparent entity using Entity Manager using a single transaction. Below are my code:
Entity Classes
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "GrandParent", schema = "testDbo")
public class GrandParent implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "LADDER_SEQUENCE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected UUID ladderSequenceId;

    @Column(name = "LADDER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String ladderId;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_NAME")
    protected String ladderName;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_ACCOUNT_NBR")
    protected String ladderAccountNumber;
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TS")
    protected LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ladder")
    private List<Parent> ladderRungs;
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Parent", schema = "testDbo")
public class Parent implements Serializable{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "LADDER_RUNG_SEQUENCE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID ladderRungSequenceId;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_ID")
    protected String ladderId;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_RUNG_NBR")
    protected Integer ladderRungNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LADDER_SEQUENCE_ID", nullable = false)
    GrandParent ladder;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "rung")
    protected List<Child> rungPositions;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child" , schema = "testDbo")
public class Child implements Serializable{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "LADDER_POSITION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected UUID ladderPositionId;

    @Column(name = "LADDER_RUNG_NBR")
    protected Integer ladderRungNumber;
    @Column(name = "POSITION_QTY")
    protected BigDecimal positionQuantity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LADDER_RUNG_SEQUENCE_ID", referencedColumnName = "LADDER_RUNG_SEQUENCE_ID")
    protected Parent rung;
}

DBService code:
@Service
public class EntityManagerDBService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    EntityManager em;
    public void ladderDBStartTransaction(){
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    public GrandParent getLadderByAccountNumberAndLadderId(String accountNumber, String ladderId){
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * from testDbo.GrandParent ld where ld.LADDER_ACCOUNT_NBR = :accountNum and ld.ladder_id = :ladderId", GrandParent.class);
        query.setParameter("accountNum", accountNumber);
        query.setParameter("ladderId", ladderId);

        if(!query.getResultList().isEmpty()){
            return (GrandParent)query.getSingleResult();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @jakarta.transaction.Transactional
    public void deleteChild(List<Child> childList){
        for(Child child : childList){
            if(!em.contains(child)){
                em.merge(child);
            }
            em.remove(child);
        }
    }

    @jakarta.transaction.Transactional
    public void saveGrandParent(GrandParent grandParent){
        try{
            for(Parent parent : grandParent.getLadderRungs()){
                for(Child child : parent.getRungPositions()){
                    if(!em.contains(child)){
                        //None Worked
                        em.merge(child);
                        //em.persist(child);
                    }
                }
            }
            grandParent.setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime.now());//Updating Grandparent
            em.merge(grandParent); //Want to save updated Grandparent
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

Application Code:
@Autowired
EntityManagerDBService entityManagerDBService;

entityManagerDBService.ladderDBStartTransaction();
        GrandParent grandParent = entityManagerDBService.getLadderByAccountNumberAndLadderId(this.accountNumber, this.ladderId);
        log.info("GrandParent : {}", grandParent);

        try{
            List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Child child : grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3).getRungPositions()){
                Child childToSave = child.clone();
                childToSave.setRung(grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3));
                childToSave.setPositionQuantity(new BigDecimal("10"));
                childList.add(childToSave);
            }
            entityManagerDBService.deleteChild(grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3).getRungPositions());
            grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3).getRungPositions().addAll(childList);
            entityManagerDBService.saveGrandParent(grandParent);
        }catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Log and Exception
2024-06-19 22:08:16 INFO com.service.cd.CDLUpdateRungService 82 : LOCAL-1 : GrandParent : 
 GrandParent{ladderSequenceId=95a85ab3-fb83-46db-8a8b-530617a05560, ladderId='00276', ladderName='TestLadder', ladderAccountNumber='X04977780', ladderRungs=[
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=9b49bb00-a395-4d41-88b9-36df45623335, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=3, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=9874a624-1cd5-49c6-9db0-e1479339f4f7, ladderRungNumber=3}]}, 
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=32fc34e3-5d84-4589-a9bd-f01da276b084, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=1, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=92e5cc6e-ab63-48da-a0b0-d2a624919c56, ladderRungNumber=1}]}, 
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=f17b5f20-dd53-4469-b382-efabd3a2e0a1, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=4, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=fc5bf7b6-7ca3-4c1a-8511-7806894deff6, ladderRungNumber=4}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=a8303128-c24c-4d60-9a5b-90215db2bc88, ladderRungNumber=4}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=693be613-ae00-4949-a253-fb720cb2f241, ladderRungNumber=4}]}, 
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=7482ee82-1e3d-41b1-81b3-82fa76e230f0, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=2, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=f276b538-2ec7-4353-aa93-2ddc66dd1741, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=31e49ce5-abea-4bdf-bad0-8ae05a5594d3, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=1952e6ad-1e0c-4cb1-ba7b-31af88a075e2, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=53188e4b-bdcb-4189-88d8-eee7c748414f, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=6009dffc-5179-4174-9efb-a78726e8b78f, ladderRungNumber=2}]}]}
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : detached entity passed to persist: com.model.entities.Child
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:721)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy139.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.fmr.fbt.fi.ladder.service.db.EntityManagerDBService.saveGrandParent(EntityManagerDBService.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

Here I am trying to create new Child Entities and save to the database. Before saving to database i want to delete that first. So, called the remove method. I debug the code and found "remove" was never called but throwing any exception even, it seems the call was ignored. And during saving it is giving the exception as mentioned. For new child entity i tried to use the "persist" method.
get Exception:
Converting org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException to JPA PersistenceException : detached entity passed to persist:
If I enable "merge" method, getting below exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [com.model.entities.Child#]
Question
What's wrong i am doing here?

The Removing a detached instance exception is thrown when you try to delete an entity that is already detached from the persistence context.
In your case, the grandParent entity is being retrieved using a separate EntityManager instance created in grandParentRepository.findByLadderIdAndLadderAccountNumber.
This EntityManager instance is different from the one created in ladderDBStartTransaction. Therefore, when you try to delete the entity, it is detached from the EntityManager created in ladderDBStartTransaction and the exception is thrown.
To delete the entity, you need to merge it into the persistence context. This will make the entity managed by the EntityManager and you can then delete it.
public void deleteGrandParent(String ladderId, String accountNumber){
    GrandParent grandParent = grandParentRepository.findByLadderIdAndLadderAccountNumber(ladderId, accountNumber);
    log.info("GrandParent Entity : {}", grandParent);
    try{
        em.remove(em.contains(grandParent) ? grandParent : em.merge(grandParent));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

You can found more information in this article
have a nice day - kevin

as per your last comment i tried to use a single transaction for whole functionality that i wanted to implement and wanted to have a better handling over DB Transactions. But it never worked. Not sure what i am still missing here. Just a quick note, if i don't handle the EntityManager by myself, and let Springboot JPA handle the transactions it would work fine, but sadly it will have two transactions. On that case if insert/update failed i don't have option to rollback the deletes. I have updated the post with updated code.
